# How to renew or invalidate cache using SimpleCachingPageFilter in Ehcache?

Tags: java, json, caching, ehcache

we are using web-ehcache's net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter, that configured by xml, to cache page where is JSON message, but this message can be changed by administrator. How to invalidate cache when administrator changes changes the JSON message?

Comment: same issue is here http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4720.page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to make it:

```
CacheManager.getInstance().getEhcache("CacheName").removeAll();
```

It gets singletone CacheManager, then gets Ehcache depending on name of cache, then removes elements.

In next request to that cached page, filter looks for Ehcache, finds, but without elementx and UPDATES elements!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by setting a time to live to 5 minutes:

```
<cache name="SimplePageCachingFilter"
     maxElementsInMemory="100"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="300"
     timeToLiveSeconds="300"
     overflowToDisk="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for good idea, if you interested i posted another question about ehcache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954683/using-ehcache-to-create-cachingfilter